# Weather app that displays "feels like" temperature?

Tags: applications, weather

I have a HTC Evo and while I like the stock weather app, it doesn't show the "feels like" temperature. I know the Weather Channel app has this but it was completely unusable with null errors for me (refer to the marketplace reviews for more on this), and the free Weatherbug app I also tried didn't have "feels like" temps. Does anybody know of any other apps that have this feature?

Comment: Do you mean "Wind chill"?

Comment: @Arda Probably includes that and humidity effects.

Comment: "Feels like" is Accuweather's proprietary wind-chill +/- secret sauce value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accuweather has two apps that give you "RealFeel" - [Accuweather](http://www.appbrain.com/app/accuweather-com/com.accuweather.android) and [Accuweather Quick](http://www.appbrain.com/app/accu-weather-quick/com.accuweather.android.simpleweather).

Comment: Accuweather Quick did it for me. Accuweather doesn't work at all with GPS turned off.